# How to read lines and create files removing https://

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want a bash script to read a file with n line and do the following

1.Pass the line as input to a python file ( Its done, no issues )
2.Create a file and redirect the output of the python

```sh
for line in $(cat file.txt)
do
 touch $line-links
 python file.py $line > $line-links
done
```

the problem is file.txt consists of links in the form of https://www.example.com.
And when I execute the bash, it's throwing an error

```sh
touch: https://www.example.com-links.txt: No such file or directory
```

I realized I have to remove the https:// portion, but how to create the file removing https:// from the line

Comment: If you are the maintainer of the Python program, you can do the creation of the file from within it, instead of doing a separated `touch` and indirect redirection. Aside from this, you don't need the `touch` anyway, since you are redirecting to the touched file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple variable expansion.

See:

```
for line in $(cat file.txt)
do
 url=${line##*//} 
 touch ${url}-links
 python file.py $ > ${url}-links
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this python script. Save this as `update_line.py` and then `python update_line.py`. This will remove all the https:// in the file

```
fpath = 'file.txt'
with open(fpath, 'r+') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  f.seek(0)
  f.truncate()
  for line in lines:
     line = line.replace('https://', '')
     f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
for line in $(cat file.txt)
do
 touch ${line-links/https:\/\//}
 python file.py $line > ${line-links/https:\/\//}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while read loop and parameter expansion.

```
while IFS= read -r url; do
  url=${url#*${url%%':'*}}
  url=${url#*'//'}
  > "$url"
  python file.py "$url" > "${url}-links"
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution in a different way

```sh
for line in $(cat file.txt)
do
 echo $line | cut -d"/" -f3 | grep "\S" | xargs touch
 python file.py $line > $line
done
```

grep "\S" is used to remove blank lines , the output will be domain.com file created

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, this is one of them :)

```
for line in $(cat file.txt)
do

 domain=$( echo $line | awk -F '//' {'print $2'} ) 
 touch "$domain-links"
 $python file.py $line > $domain-links

done
```

Comment: I got the solution creating file name using xargs , but this is the best solution

Comment: @Gabrial nah, this is an excellent example of useless use of cat and awk

Comment: Why is python a variable? Did you mean `${domain}-links` rather than the new variable `$domain-links`? (snake_case exists because the minus sign could be algebraic).

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed command to accomplish the task

```
 for line in $(cat file.txt)
    do
     variable=$( echo 'https://www.example.com' | sed 's/https\?:\/\///') | touch $variable // Using Sed to strip the https://
     $python file.py $line > $line-links

    done
```